# Check a revision exists for a node

Tags: nodes

How do I check there is a revision exists for a node? I can load the node details using the following code.

```
$nid = "my_node_id"; 
$node_details = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
```

How do I check if there is a revision for a node? Putting it differently: How can I get the revision ID of a node after creating a new revision?

I create a new revision using this code.

```
  $original_revision = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
  $original_revision->my_field_to_be_modified= "my_value";
  $original_revision->setNewRevision(TRUE);
  $original_revision->setRevisionCreationTime($time_stamp);
  $original_revision->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getRevisionId();` The revision identifier of the entity, or NULL if the entity does not have a revision identifier.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21RevisionableInterface.php/function/RevisionableInterface%3A%3AgetRevisionId/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

alter way query form database and check $count if 1 mean it exists else 0

```
$count = \Drupal::database()
        ->select('node_revision')
        ->condition('vid', {revision_number})
        ->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
```